# How do you fake cookies in capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, capybara, session-cookies

I am testing an app that would be installed on a sub domain to take advantage of the cookies created by the main app. How ever unless both apps are running on, say: `site.local.com` the app I am testing doesn't have access to a session controller, thus I cannot create cookies in testing via typical sign in methods.

So my question is, how do I - in capybara - fake cookies? I have tried something like:

```
it "should ... ", type: :request do
  sign_in(@user)
  ...
end

#sign_in definition:
def sign_in(user) 
  cookies.signed[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
end
```

How ever the issue is:

```
 Failure/Error: sign_in(@user)
 NameError:
   undefined local variable or method `cookies' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_2:0x000000090cd998>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
page.driver.browser.set_cookie("auth_token=#{user.auth_token}")
```